# ANCM In-Process Start Failure on ISS for ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web Application

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, hosting, http-error

I have just migrated my *ASP.NET Core version 2.2* to ***ASP.NET Core version 3.1***.  I have configured the web site to run under IIS *In-Process* mode.  The application runs locally hosted with *IIS Express*.

During final testing, I deployed to a test site hosted on our *IIS version 10* web server.  As before, the site ran as expected.  Today, I deployed the same build to the production web site, running on the *same IIS server* and constantly receive the following error:

```
HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure
```

My first thought was that there must be a difference in the Application Pool configuration between the two web sites, or perhaps a permissions difference between the two application pool identities, but visual inspection shows that both sites have the same configuration - the only difference that I can see is that the web site bindings are to two different URLs.

I then wondered if there was a difference between the two file installations, so I manually deleted the contents of the production site and copied the files from the staging site.  This made no difference and the *ANCM In-Process Start Failure* remains.

I could see nothing unusual in the IIS logs, but if I look in the Windows event logs I see an error stating:

```
Unable to access appsettings.json in C:\Windows\System32
```

I can't find any references to this error on-line, but it seems that dor some reason it is not referencing the installing folder of `C:\WWW\Reporting` but defaulting to the server's Windows folder.  I suspect this is the clue, but I do not know where to look to fix it.

If I update the `web-config` file and change the hosting model to *'OutOfProcess'* the site runs correctly.

#### Summary

Two *exact* copies of the same *ASP.NET Core version 3.1* web site, installed in directories next to each other, on the *same web server* using the *same IIS instance*, one site runs correctly, the other site errors with the `ANCM In-Process Start Failure` HTTP error.

From the Windows Event logs, the site appears to be trying to start from the `C:\Windows\System32` folder rather than its installed IIS web folder.

#### Code Snippets

**Reporting.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    <NeutralLanguage>en-GB</NeutralLanguage>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

***Program.cs***

```
var config = ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env}.json", true)
    .Build();

var webHost = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel()
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .UseIIS()
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseConfiguration(configuration);

webHost.Build().Run();
```

#### Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore"
             path="*"
             verb="*"
             modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2"
             resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet"
                  arguments=".\Reporting.dll"
                  stdoutLogEnabled="false"
                  stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"
                  hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

### Update

The Windows Event log is reporting the following error:

```
Application '/LM/W3SVC/106/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\www\Reporting\' hit unexpected managed exception, exception code = '0xe0434352'. First 30KB characters of captured stdout and stderr logs:
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The physical path is 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appsettings.json'.
```

This looks odd, as I was expecting the application to load the `appsettings.json` file from the root of the application ('C:\www\Reporting')

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html Run a report and see what it says.

Comment: Could you please share the web.config file settings?

Comment: Added the Web.config file and also found an error in the Windows event log which looks like it might be the problem, but I don't know why it would be looking in the 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\' folder for the 'appsettings.json' file.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, as is so often the case, the solution was simple, but I had missed it in the deployments docs.

In my case at least, the 2.2 version, running `out-of-process` only required ***Read*** permissions to the installed directly.  With the 3.1 version, running `in-process`, the application permissions simply needed increasing to ***Read and Execute***.

I hope that helps someone else who has missed this configuration change.